# Как посчитать сколько раз встречается слово в тексте

Tags: javascript

Как на js можно посчитать сколько раз слово встречается в строке, пробую таким способом, оно по идее работает, но встречаю проблему когда в тексте это слово встречается дважды подряд написанным текстом, как можно сделать этот код более правильно?

```
var textToChange='тест тестовый тесттест' 
alert(textToChange.split('тест').length - 1)
```

Код в примере выводит 3, хотя правильнее должен  выводить 1

Comment: здравствуйте. Поясните, пожалуйста, почему код должен выводить 1? вы проверяете на "тест", но такого слова у вас в строке вообще нет. Может быть "текст"?

Comment: извиняюсь, не заметил, это я просто перекопировал код из основной программы, и для примера это вставил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение вашей задачи:

```
const textToChange='тест тестовый тесттест'

const getWordsCount = (string) => (string.trim().match(/([^а-я]тест[^а-я]|тест[^а-я])/ig) || []).length

getWordsCount(textToChange) // 1
```

Comment: для `'тест тестовый тест тест'` вместо 3 выводит 2

Answer (score 2):

Так Вы же разбиваете строку по вхождению "тест". Оно у Вас 3 раза встречается — вот 3 и показывает. Вам надо разбивать строку по пробелам и искать слово:

```js
const textToChange='текст тест тестовый тесттест' 
alert(textToChange.split(' ').filter( (value) => value === 'тест').length)
```